# Adding elements from each sub array in a 2D array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, parsing, multidimensional-array

So I have this 2D permutations array of ints which looks like this:

```js
arr = [
  [ 5, 2, 6 ],
  [ 2, 5, 6 ],
  [ 6, 5, 2 ],
  [ 5, 6, 2 ],
  [ 2, 6, 5 ],
  [ 6, 2, 5 ]
]
```

and essentially I want to be able to get a **string** that looks like this '652,625,562,526,256'

This means that the numbers are ordered and are in string format.

What I have done so far is:

```js
arr.map(c => c.join("")).join()
```

Which combines it to a array, however now my thought process would be to convert this to a array of ints and then order and re-parse as strings, but there must be some kind of easier way to do this?

I'm quite new to JavaScript so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do the second join immediately - instead, sort the array of joined strings first, *then* join:

```js
const arr = [
  [ 5, 2, 6 ],
  [ 2, 5, 6 ],
  [ 6, 5, 2 ],
  [ 5, 6, 2 ],
  [ 2, 6, 5 ],
  [ 6, 2, 5 ]
];

const result = arr
  .map(subarr => subarr.join(''))
  .sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a, undefined, { numeric: true }))
  .join();
console.log(result);
```

or map to numbers and subtract in the comparator:

```js
const arr = [
  [ 5, 2, 6 ],
  [ 2, 5, 6 ],
  [ 6, 5, 2 ],
  [ 5, 6, 2 ],
  [ 2, 6, 5 ],
  [ 6, 2, 5 ]
];

const result = arr
  .map(subarr => Number(subarr.join('')))
  .sort((a, b) => b - a)
  .join();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I needed! I did not know you can compare the string values and had to convert them to int

Comment: While I think it's cleaner to keep it, it's useful to note that we could skip the `Number` constructor in the second example.  Subtraction will coerce the strings to numbers anyway.